# OWA 2010 calendar is it possible to get the 2003 week view back or customize it?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-web-app

In OWA (Exchange Outlook) 2003 calendar, there was a week view, which was a simple list type view, showing the day, time, and details.   In OWA 2010, this is gone and the week view shows a more graphical view with boxes spanning the time slots.   It is very difficult to read when you have many appointments.

Is there a way to get a list style view, or some way to customize the views in OWA 2010 so I can build one?

[image: old outlook owa weekly (list) view]

[image: new outlook weekly view]

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?  Have you tried logging in to the OWA light, or enabling the blind/low vision option, which reverts it to an older looking UI?

Comment: I know it can be done in Outlook, not sure in OWA...haven't seen OWA 2010 in a while now to remember.

Comment: Have tried light, no list view there.   I just tried blind/low vision and it does not seem to have public folders (where the calendar is) and will not accept the url if I go directly.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to modify the aspx or .js files?  (though it would be nice to keep the stock view also)

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe so.

http://www.it.northwestern.edu/collaborate/how-to/owa-basic-training.html#customcalendar

> Customize OWA Calendar View
>
> OWA has four views you can use to display your schedule and
>   appointments:
>
> - Day View – Displays a single day’s appointments by the hour.
> - Work Week View – Displays appointments in a 5 day format: Monday through    Friday.
> - Week View – Displays appointments for the entire week: Sunday    through  Saturday.
> - Month View – Displays appointments for the entire    month.